# Read SQL Agent Error Logs With Powershell

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell

I can easily read the SQL Error Logs using the below code but cannot find a way to read the Agent Error Logs. Does anyone know if it is possible?

```
    $sqlServer = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") $server
    $sqlServer.ReadErrorLog()
```

I've searched through the namespaces and there isn't anything obvious pointing me to the logs. I have tried this without success.

```
    $sqlAgent = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent") $server
    $sqlAgent.ReadErrorLog()
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the `JobServer` object? Specifically the [`ReadErrorLog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms201497.aspx) method?

Comment: Obviously not...feel better about yourself?

Comment: Sorry if my phrasing was a little harsh, but I'm genuinely perplexed by how few people seem to consult the documentation before posting.

Comment: Thanks Pondlife...I had dug around for several hours before posting. Unfortunately, I am very unfamiliar with PowerShell and was looking in the wrong place. I was expecting the Read to be directly under the Agent as it is in Server. I'd actually looked under JobService but had missed the method. In retrospect, R comes before S so I should have seen it! Ultimately, most everything is documented somewhere...the trick is finding it in a timely fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Pondlife was correct. For anyone else facing this problem, this worked for my purposes.

```
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null

    $sqlServer = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") $server
    $jobServer = $sqlServer.JobServer;
    $jobServer.ReadErrorLog() | 
    where { ($_.ErrorLevel -lt 3) -and ($_.LogDate -ge $(Get-Date).AddDays($EventLogDaysToReview))  } |
    Format-Table -AutoSize -wrap
```